# Why isn't LocalDateTime actually a local date and time?

Tags: .net, nodatime

As a software architect, I would really like to use NodaTime but it's concept of 'Local' is making our code extremely difficult to work with (and it is driving me and my team nuts)! The [documentation](http://nodatime.org/unstable/userguide/concepts.html), when referring to "local" and "global" times states the following:

> The key difference is that people all around the world will agree on
>   a *global* value simultaneously, whereas they may all see different
>   *local* values for the same global value, **due to time zones**.

This sentence is defining what Global time means by using the definition of Local time. Therefore, before we can understand Global time we must first understand what Local time means.

Google (and many other dictionaries similarly) defines "[Local Time](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=negates%20definition)" as:

> Time as reckoned in a particular region or *time zone*.
>
> - time at a particular place as measured from the sun's transit over the meridian at that place, defined as noon.

So, Local time is a specific time that is defined by (or is bound to) a **time zone** - got it. Now we fully understand what Global time means; okay, next sentence:

> A local value has **no** associated *time zone* in Noda Time;

**Wait! What the...?!** The documentation just got done defining Global time by using the universally accepted definition of Local time (which **is** associated to a time zone) and now they decides to completely negates its meaning, if that's true, what does Global time now mean? IMHO, absolutely nothing.

The documentation goes on to state...

> in particular it is **not** just "a date and time fixed to the *local time* of the computer running the code"

I have two problems with this statement:

1. the documentation cannot using the universal definition of 'local time' to *try* to describe what it is not. That's like saying: `X is equal to (NOT X) is true`.
2. Since using the computer's date and time is *exactly* the definition of "Local Time", then what am I to call local time?

I vote that we use a better definition than 'Local', how about the word 'Raw'? Which means:

> Being in or nearly in the natural state: not processed or purified.

Hmmm....

> A [raw] value has **no** associated *time zone* in Noda Time;
>   in particular it is **not** just "a date and time fixed to the *local time* of the computer running the code"

Now that sounds more like the definition the documentation is trying to convey.

Or perhaps, someone else can come up with a better word than 'Raw'; but the point is, please give us back the real meaning of 'Local' since 'Local' has a very real and very useful meaning in software and in life.

Therefore, can we rename the `Local[Date][Time]` classes to `Raw[Date][Time]` and (optionally) add new classes called `Local[Date][Time]` that **is** bound to the computer's Local time zone?

---

@Michal & @J... -

The problem we are having isn't understanding `LocalDateTime` in 'our' local (because it is zoneless). The problem we are having with LocalDateTime is that it **is** zoneless. In essence, `LocalDateTime` *should be*, by definition, a special type of `ZonedDateTime`. (Just like UTC is conceptually (and concretely) a special type of `ZonedDateTime`. Thus, UTC could have it's own set of types, like: `Utc[Date][Time]`; which, given the right problem domain, could be very useful. And because `UtcDateTime` hasn't been 'taken' we could create such a concept without interfering with NodaTime.)

Back to our problem, for example: if I have two ZonedDateTimes, one from New York and the other from Seattle and I want to study these two ZonedDateTimes from my current location (let's say: Dallas). I would like to write...

```
LocalDateTime fromNy = newYork.LocalDateTime; 
LocalDateTime fromWa = seattle.LocalDateTime;
```

But instead, I get two unrelated local date times that have absolutely no relationships to each other. In fact, if it wasn't for the var names I wouldn't know which is which.

What I want, is two ZonedDateTimes that have been converted to *my* local time zone, as the property name suggests. Now, these two *LocalDateTime* values (where LocalDateTime is a special type of ZonedDateTime) have relevant meaning. I know I can get some what close to what I want by doing the following; but it is messy, doesn't convey the same semantics and it looses the time zone information.

```
DateTimeZone ct = BclDateTimeZone.ForSystemDefault();
LocalDateTime tx1 = newYork.WithZone(ct);
LocalDateTime tx2 = seattle.WithZone(ct);
```

I would also like to be able to convert the values again like so:

```
ZonedDateTime wa = tx2.WithZone(seattleTimeZone);
ZonedDateTime nw = tx2.WithZone(nyTimeZone);
```

Which would also allow for:

```
instant.InUtc();
instant.InZone(zone);
instant.InLocal();
```

Thus having the ability to map Instant time to the 3 most common time zones; UTC, local and other. But I can't since LocalDateTime isn't a special type of ZonedDateTime.

IMHO, NodaTime 1.x is nice but it isn't flexible (or fluid) enough for prime time use. But the good news is, it isn't that far from it. Hopefully, in 2.0 (or sooner) these issues can be addressed.

@Michal - I like your idea of `Noda[Date][Time]` as opposed to `Raw[Date][Time]`.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. The post wasn't stated as a question. - Now fixed.

Comment: "IMHO, NodaTime 1.x is nice but it isn't flexible (or fluid) enough for prime time use." I don't see any evidence of this in your post, other than that you don't like our use of the term "Local" (which matches both Joda Time and java.time, btw). All you need to do is use your system default time zone for a `ZonedDateTime` and you're fine, aren't you? Note that `WithZone` doesn't return a `LocalDateTime`, it returns a `ZonedDateTime` (precisely because it has a zone). I would also suggest that the system default time zone is almost never a useful one in server-side work. More so in client-side.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no answerable question.  This sort of feedback is great, but belongs in a discussion group, not on StackOverflow.

Comment: However, one way that I suggest thinking about it is that there are *many different locals*.  Consider a `DateTime` where `.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local`.  That local *does* mean the computer's own time zone, but that information easily gets lost as soon as you store or serialize.  That said, there is one case where `LocalDateTime` is essential but the naming is not clear, and that's for the idea of "floating times". Example: A TV show that airs "2015-03-22 18:00:00", which actually airs at different instants across multiple time zones.

Comment: Indeed. That's why I've tried to use "system default" or something similar everywhere - "local" is too ambiguous IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are probably getting confused with is this:

`LocalDateTime` = A generic time in a specific calendar (e.g. Gregorian) but as there is no `TimeZone` attached to it, you cannot distinguish which exact point on the Global time line this happened. Imagine this to be just a generic value. E.g. `14:00`. You won't know when exactly `14:00` is because your are missing what TimeZone this is in.

`ZonedDateTime` = `LocalDateTime` in a specific time zone (what you probably are imagining as `LocalDateTime`).

I probably do agree with you that it is a bit mis-leading. And I would prefer for it to be called `NodaDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` to be called `LocalDateTime` as it does seem more logical that way.

**EDIT - following comment**

Personally, I rarely use the `LocalDateTime` if you stick between `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` you will probably get rid of a lot of your headaches. There is a very nice overview diagram of converting between the types:

Taken From: [nodatime.org - User Guide - Converting Between Types](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/type-choices.html)

[image: nodatime.org - User Guide - Converting Between Types]

So in your case what you want to be doing, is converting from a specific`ZoneDateTime` to `Instant`, and then back to your desired `ZonedDateTime` (your system tz)

E.g.

```
var myTz = BclDateTimeZone.ForSystemDefault();

var fromNy = SystemClock.Instance.Now.InZone(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"]);
// fromNy = 2015-03-22T08:28:56 America/New_York (-04)

var fromLa = SystemClock.Instance.Now.InZone(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Los_Angeles"]);
// fromLa = 2015-03-22T05:28:56 America/Los_Angeles (-07)

var fromNyInMyTz = fromNy.ToInstant().InZone(myTz);
// localFromNy = 2015-03-22T12:28:56 GMT Standard Time (+00)

var fromLaInMyTz = fromLa.ToInstant().InZone(myTz);
// localFromLa = 2015-03-22T12:28:56 GMT Standard Time (+00)
```

You could also create an extension method:

```
public static class NodaExtensions
{
    public static ZonedDateTime InUtc(this ZonedDateTime dt)
    {
        return dt.ToInstant().InUtc();
    }
    public static ZonedDateTime InZone(this ZonedDateTime dt, DateTimeZone tz)
    {
        return dt.ToInstant().InZone(tz);
    }
    public static ZonedDateTime InLocal(this ZonedDateTime dt)
    {
        return dt.ToInstant().InZone(BclDateTimeZone.ForSystemDefault());
    }
}
```

allowing for:

```
var fromNyInUtc = fromNy.InUtc();
var fromLaInUtc = fromLa.InUtc();

var fromNyInZone = fromNy.InZone(myTz);
var fromLaInZone = fromLa.InZone(myTz);

var fromNyInLocal = fromNy.InLocal();
var fromLaInLocal = fromLa.InLocal();
```

Is this something you would prefer?

Comment: Personally, I think `LocalDateTime` makes perfect sense.  Consider daylight savings time - if I look at my clock and calendar at 1:30am before the fall change, then again an hour later the "local date and time" will read the same.  Only when it is zoned (ie: BST vs GMT, or EDT vs EST) do we know what the global time actually is in both instances.  I think Noda has a clearer nomenclature in this case than the dictionary.  It's not atypical for science and engineering to use words to mean a more precise thing than the accepted variety of popular definitions.

Comment: Michal, like all your great comments, I like your extension methods and it would work wonders for most developers. However, in our current domain the concept of Local is a very real idea. Therefore, we are very seriously thinking for forking the code... until just now. I just realized (as I'm writing this), instead of renaming `Local[Date][Time]` to `Noda[Date][Time]`; I've decide to create a near clone of Zoned[Date][Time] and call it `LocalZoned[Date][Time]` that way we don't have to maintain our own fork. Between LocalZoned + Extensions I think we can get there! Thanks.